# How to iterate request attribute in struts 2?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I'm trying to iterate request attribute from `ActionSupport` in JSP page name `EnergyConsumptionAnalysis` on page load to display it on browser using struts2 using same JSP page, but at runtime I'm getting empty display. Could anyone please tell me what's wrong I'm doing?

JSP:

```
<s:action name = "FetchSite"></s:action>
  <s:iterator value="siteData">
        <s:property value = "name"/>
  </s:iterator>
```

Action support:

```
public class EnergyAction extends ActionSupport implements  ServletRequestAware
{
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @Override
    public String execute()
            throws Exception {
        //Get the site Data
        EnergyAnalysisBusinessHandler handler = new EnergyAnalysisBusinessHandler();

        //setting attribute as arraylist type
        request.setAttribute("siteData", handler.getSiteData());
        return SUCCESS;
   }

    public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request){
        this.request = request;
    }

    public HttpServletRequest getServletRequest(){
    return request;
  }
```

struts.xml:

```
<action name = "FetchSite" class = "com.javaworld.email.EnergyAction">
               <result name = "success">jsp/EnergyConsumptionAnalysis.jsp
               </result>
 </action>
```

Comment: i am not sure why you trying to play with request object when u have better option to use value stack by simple use of getter and setter.i will go with `Vasily Komarov` sugestion

Comment: I'm new in struts, I didn't know about it. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @Stardust beware of one thing value stack extend the scope and your parameters are available in redirect also, the usual behaviour of redirect will ignore any parameters set in the initial request, so check your use case if you really want this

Comment: @mprabhat: i don't see that as a big issue or something which can create any majoy issue

Comment: You increase the scope of a parameter used that itself is a big issue if it is not intended

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1 Your are trying to take siteData from value stack, but your put it in request.
This way your can take it from request:

```
<s:iterator value="#request.siteData">
        <s:property value = "name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

2 The simpliest way to pass some parameters to your .jsp is create getters/setters in your Action. No need to put parameters in request at all.

Action:

```
    public class EnergyAction extends ActionSupport
    {
        private Object siteData;

        @Override
        public String execute()
                throws Exception {
            //Get the site Data
            EnergyAnalysisBusinessHandler handler = new EnergyAnalysisBusinessHandler();
            siteData = handler.getSiteData();
            return SUCCESS;
       }

        public void setSiteData(Object siteData){
            this.siteData = siteData;
        }

        public Object getSiteData(){
            return siteData;
        }
    }
```

JSP:

```
<s:iterator value="siteData">
  <s:property value = "name"/>
</s:iterator>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<s:iterator value="siteData">
        <s:property value = "name"/>
  </s:iterator>
```

you can use this:

```
<s:iterator value="%{#request.siteData}">
        <s:property value = "name"/>
  </s:iterator>
```